# How to say Space Fox?

Tags: translation

Any suggestions on how to say and write Space Fox? As in a fox from outer space? I've been using 宇宙狐 uchuu kitsune うちゅうきつね

Is that correct or would you suggest something different?

Comment: I would rendaku it as うちゅう***ぎ***つね, but that's just my gut feeling.

Comment: It's interesting. I didn't know that きつね is prone to rendaku until I checked this: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%8F%E7%8B%90

Answer (score -1):

宇宙のフォックス

うちゅう means "space" and フォックス means "fox".

Why do you want to use this word？